# Calendar event becomes invite iOS 9

Tags: ios, exchange, exchange-activesync, office-365

I installed iOS 9 (then 9.1). After that when i edit a calendar event on my iPhone (6 plus or 5s) it appears as a Invite in outlook (2013) on my PC. Got Office 365 that i manage myself. Really wierd. I got full rights read/write (set to owner) so it doesn't seem to be a owner issue...

Any ideas why this happens?

I tried with an old iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2) and that does not change the event.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the exact same issue.  Outlook 2013 which synchronizes with Office 365, I-Phone 6S Plus with IOS 9.1

If I modify or create a calendar entry on my I-phone, it changes the calendar entry to an invite in Outlook.  In Outlook the calendar entry is shown with a semi-colon and followed by my name.

If I open the calendar entry, the To... field is displayed empty and an information message: "You haven't sent this meeting invitation yet."

If I click on "Cancel Invitation", the entry becomes a calendar entry again and the Invite disappears...  Until I edit it with the I-Phone.

Hmmm...

Comment: Obviously it's a iOS 9 issue. At first i thought they had switched or add some new features to the calendar function, but when i compare it to older bersions of iOS i can't seem to figure out what